# Adding multiple folders as input to a bash script separted by a separator

Tags: linux, bash

User will input the folders varying in number but maximum 10, separated by a comma and in the end specify the name of the output file

```
./script.sh folder1,folder2,folder3,folder4 -o output.csv
```

```
./script.sh folder1,folder2,folder3, -o output.csv
```

Comment: Why do it this way instead of having them be separate arguments?

Comment: you could have it simple with *positional parameters* (as @Barmar suggested), arguments can be treated like usual folder names (containing spaces) for example *'./script.sh folder1 "folder 2" folder\ 3 -o output.csv'*